# Jquery Valid() function only apply on 1st element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am intend to use javascript to submit the form. Before I want to submit the form, I need to validate my form.

The following is my code :

```js
alert("OP Please edit me to add the validation script code, cdn link or something. Add code that triggers the validation.");

function validateForm1() {
  $("#addMapForm").validate();
  $('#addMapForm').valid();
  console.log($('#addMapForm').valid());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Admin/AddMap" method="post" id="addMapForm">
  <div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Location Name *</label>
        <input class="form-control" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Unit/ Floor Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address*</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" style="height:100px" required></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Town/ City *</label>
        <input class="form-control" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Zip Code*</label>
        <input class="form-control" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show the markup and perhaps put the markup and code in a snippet (CTRL-M when editing) with a functioning example.  Include a link the the actual validation code you are using.  Help us make no assumptions or guesses to best assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `name`s on the inputs. A form will only submit named controls and validation plugin won't validate anything without a `name`

The `required` fields work fine once you add them

```js
$("#addMapForm").validate();
$("#addMapForm").valid();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Admin/AddMap" method="post" id="addMapForm">
  <div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Location Name *</label>
        <input name="location" class="form-control" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Unit/ Floor Number</label>
        <input  name="unit" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address*</label>
        <textarea  name="address" class="form-control" style="height:100px" required></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Town/ City *</label>
        <input name="city" class="form-control" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Zip Code*</label>
        <input name="zip" class="form-control" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Pretty much the same as I was doing, got distracted before I posted mine :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using this: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Have you implemented the rules of validation for other elements?

> rules (default: rules are read from markup (classes, attributes, data))

So either you have those defined in HTML or you need to define them inside validate function called before you called `.valid()`.

Here is an examle:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
    name: "required",
    // compound rule
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
});
```

In short for more precise help we need all the relevant code or fiddle, plunker a demo showing the example of the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
$('.form-control').each(function() {
    $(this).validate();
    $(this).valid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the following js to validate all my form, however i know the following code is not the best answer, it only able to show the error message on the first input element.

I am welcome to anyone to post better answer than this.

```
    function validateForm() {
        var result = true;
        $("#addMapForm").each(function () {
            $(this).find(':input').each(function () {

                if ($(this).valid() == false) {
                    result = false;
                    return;
                }

            });
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave your form inputs some name attributes.  Not sure if you added the actual code to your page, so I did so here. I added a button to trigger just for a demo.  I added the simplest bit of CSS.

```js
$("#validateme").on('click', function() {
  console.log("validating");
  let Validator = $("#addMapForm").validate();
  Validator.form();
  console.log(Validator.valid());
});
```

```css
 .error { color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Admin/AddMap" method="post" id="addMapForm">
  <div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Location Name *</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="location" required  type="text"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Unit/ Floor Number</label>
        <input class="form-control"  />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address*</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="address" style="height:100px" required></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Town/ City *</label>
        <input class="form-control" required type="text"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Zip Code*</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="zip" required />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="validateme" type="button">Do validate</button>
</form>
```